# How can I browse my Projects in a Folder Browser Dialog in a WinForm C#?

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

I'm developing a win forms application using AxosoftAPI.NET. One of the functionalities is to browse the different projects.

I'm able to login to Axosoft and get the projects via c# code. But now I want to browse the projects using folder browser dialog control in my win form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FolderBrowserDialog is only for browsing actual folders accessible in the Windows file system.  If you want to use that, you'd need to build a shell extension so that the projects show up in Windows Explorer.  That's probably complete overkill for what you are trying to achieve, so it is most likely easier to reproduce the FolderBrowserDialog's interface using your own custom control.  You should be able to use a Combo and TreeView or ListView with icons to give a similar UI.

Comment: Using a treeview is a great idea

Answer (score 0):

You can browse folder this way

```
public void ChooseFolder()
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
    }
}
```

Useful link [Folder Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984305(v=vs.71).aspx)